# Unexpected C behavior in bisection method implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, implementation, terminate

I'm trying to implement Bolzano's Bisection method in C, and while the algorithm appears to work, it terminates unexpectedly at around 4 steps
and the 4th step appears to increase the "err" and "divid" rather than have it continuously decrease. I'm trying to keep the code as simple as possible so no pointer/references/arrays/arguments in main etc please.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
//#define delta 0.00000000005
//#define epsilon 0.000000000005
//#define root1 1
//#define root2 -1
//#define maxit 7000

void bolzano(double a,double b, float root);
double function(double x);

int counter = 0;
//double err_global;//eps = 0.5e-6;
double maxit = 300;
double epsilon = 0.5E-6;
double delta = 0.5E-10;
int root1 = 1;
int root2 = -1;

int main(void){
    double a,b;
    printf("Eisagete tis times toy diastimatos [a,b]:  ");
    scanf("%lf%lf",&a,&b);
    printf("[a,b] = [%lf \\,%lf]\n",a, b);
    printf("                   ksi = %d\n", root1);
    printf("                            n   Xn   En   En+1/En");
    bolzano(a,b,root1);
    system("pause");
    printf("[a,b] = [%lf \\, %lf]\n",a, b);
    printf("                   ksi = %d", root2);
    bolzano(a,b,root2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


double function(double x){
    return pow(x-1,3) * (x+1);
}


void bolzano(double a, double b, float root){
    double c,err,divit,err_global;
    while(b - a > epsilon && counter < maxit){
        //system("pause");
        c = (a + b)/2;
        err = fabs(c - root);
        if(counter == 0 ){
            err_global = err;
            printf("                           %d   %lf   %lf      \n", counter, c, err);
            counter++;
                if(function(a) * function(c) < 0){
                    b = c;
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    a = c;
                    continue;
                }
        }
        divit = err/err_global;
        printf("                   ");
        printf("                           %d   %lf   %lf       %lf\n",counter, c ,err, divit);
        err_global = err;
        if(fabs(function(c)) < delta){
              break;
        }
        else if(function(a) * function(c) < 0){
            counter++;
            b = c;
            //continue;
        }
        else{
            counter++;
            a = c;
            //continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no good reason to use `pow` for a cube, and it might introduce more inaccuracy than the simple multiplications would.

Comment: For which input interval do you observe the described behaviour?

Comment: @M Oehm 3rd time it loops (counter =3 moving to counter  =4)

Comment: @WeatherVane I tried doing it with a simple * it had no observable results as for as I can tell. I kept pow in the code ultimately to keep it cleaner

Comment: No, no, I mean what are your input values `a` and ´b`?

Comment: Minor: `int root1` and `int root2` are being passed as the `float` argument for `bolzano()`. You have a function prototype for `bolzano` so the argument type is converted, but please enable compiler warnings to catch this type of error.

Comment: `counter` should probably be a local variable. You don't reset it between calls to `bolzano`.

Comment: @MOehm just pipped you!

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of function, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the statement: `system("pause");  is not portable.  Suggest using: `int *ch; while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the global

```
int counter = 0;
```

to control the operations in function `bolzano` which is never reset.

Please add this line at the start of `bolzano`

```
counter = 0;
```